# rendering content dynamically in react native not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to render content dynamically. I have an array of JSON data that I loop over, and, for now (testing purposes), create a text node "hey" for each element of that array,pushing it to another array called renderedData. I am trying to render the contents of this array, renderedData, but it is not working. I have no idea why - nothing is rendered, yet when I try a dummy array that is declared on the spot, such as "test", it works.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Button, TextInput, Modal, Alert, TouchableHighlight, SafeAreaView, SectionList, FlatList, ListView } from 'react-native';
import EditScreenInfo from '../components/EditScreenInfo';
import { Text, View } from '../components/Themed';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { parse } from '@babel/core';
import { getInitialURL } from 'expo-linking';

const payments: any[] = []

export default function PaymentsScreen(){
    
    const getData = async () => {

        try {
            
            const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
            const result = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys)
            return result

        } catch(e) {
        
            console.log(e)
        }

    }

    
    
    React.useEffect(() => {

        getData()

    })

    const data: (string | null)[] = []
    const renderedData: string[] = []

    async function parseData(){

        const payments = await getData()

        if (payments != null && payments != undefined) {
            
            console.log(payments)

            payments.map((eachPayment: any[]) => {
                
                if (eachPayment[1] != null && eachPayment[1].includes("{")) 
                    data.push(eachPayment[1])

            })

        }
        
        data.map((eachPayment: any) => {

            if (eachPayment != null) renderedData.push("hey")
        })

        return data
        
    }

    parseData()

    return (
         
        <View>
            {data.map((info: any) => <Text>{info}</Text>)}
        </View>
        
    )

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      marginHorizontal: 16
    },
    item: {
      backgroundColor: "#f9c2ff",
      padding: 20,
      marginVertical: 8
    },
    header: {
      fontSize: 32,
      backgroundColor: "#fff"
    },
    title: {
      fontSize: 24
    }
  });
```

[image: error]

Comment: Is you `data.push` triggered ? Try puttina console.log right before this line (but  inside the if statement), and another inside the `data.map`

Comment: I just realised what my problem is, but I do not know how to fix it. Because I am using async storage in my code (what I have given is just a snippet), I have to use "await", now, when I use await, my top level function eventually has to be declared with "await" property as well. The problem is, expo for react-native, which is what I am using, does not allow this for some reason. It cannot have "await" in a top-level function that determines what is rendered on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have async call, here is how i would do it :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  const fakeApiData = [1, 2, 3];
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
  const [renderedData, setRenderedData] = React.useState([]);


  const getApiDataAsync = () => Promise.resolve(fakeApiData);

// Equal to componentDiMount()
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // This is your async call to get your data
    const data = getApiDataAsync().then(data => setData(data));
  }, []);

  // Effect triggered after data changes, so when you get your data
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const futurRenderedData = [];
    data.map(item => futurRenderedData.push(item));
    setRenderedData(futurRenderedData);
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <div>
      {renderedData.map(item => <span>{item} </span>)}
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

The idea is to get your data, be sure to have it, either through a promise, an await, or an observable, and then setting your `renderedData`.

---

Here is your code modified, tell me if there is still something wrong :

```
export default function PaymentsScreen() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(new Array<string>());
  const [renderedData, setRenderedData] = React.useState(new Array<string>());

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
      const result = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys);
      return result;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  async function parseData() {
    const payments = await getData();

    if (payments) {
      payments.foreach((eachPayment: any[]) => {
        if (eachPayment[1] && eachPayment[1].includes('{'))
          data.push(eachPayment[1]);
      });
    }

    data.map((eachPayment: any) => {
      if (eachPayment != null) setRenderedData('hey');
    });

    return data;
  }


  React.useEffect(async () => {
    setData(await parseData());
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        {data.map((info: any) => (
          <Text>{info}</Text>
          ))}
      </View>
      <View>
        {renderedData.map(item => <span>{item} </span>)} {/*If this appear in the html then it works*/}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks, but property "then" does not exist on type "promise"

Comment: Don't use a Promise like in my example, I did it just to simulate async call. You have to adapt it to your code. If you need help then share your whole code so we can see how you do it.

Comment: thanks. i really appreciate it, I have shared all of my code

Comment: can you please help me with a few problems, firstly , ```    React.useEffect(() => {
      setData(parseData());
    }, []);
  ``` returns an error because I need to have await before parseData(), so like await parseData(), but I cannot have this because it causes so many issues. Also, my editor, vs code, is complaining about           ``` {data.map((info: any) => (
            <Text>{info}</Text>
            ))} ```, as in, it is saying the Text component cannot be there. Sorry, I don't like being spoon fed but I have worked on this for so many hours and still haven't resolved it.

Comment: You need to add async and await in the useEffect : `useEffect(async () => setData(await parseData())), [])`, I forgot it in the code, i'll edit that. About the `data.map(info => ...)` there is nothing wrong with this, it shouldn't throw any error.

Comment: Hi there, I am getting the error that "Uncaught Invariant Violation: Unexpected text node:  . A text node cannot be a child of a <View>." The page is basically blank, meaning it did not work. I edited my post to show the screenshot of the error and what I think is causing the error

Comment: i console.log many things inside parseData() function and they do not appear, I think this means parseData() is not being called. I think I found the culprit, it is in the screenshot above, where we use React useEffect, but I am not sure how to fix it. Can you please help me?

Comment: I think you need to wrap your variable 'info' in a `<Text></Text>` in the data.map (Line 44 on your screenshot). You cannot display raw text without wrapping it with